# SQL-Fast random sampling from some intermediate result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to sample from rows which satisfy some criteria, for example sample 100 users from those who are less than 25 years old.

I've tried to follow the post here https://www.sisense.com/blog/how-to-sample-rows-in-sql-273x-faster/ and gave each intermediate result an intermediate_id according to the row number, but the query (on a 7M entries table) is very slow (more than 2 seconds).
What would be a better way? here's my try:

```
with relevant_users as (select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as intermediate_id from users where age<25),
relevant_users_count as (select count(*) from relevant_users) 
select * from relevant_users
where intermediate_id in (
  select round(random() * (select * from relevant_users_count) )::integer as intermediate_id
  from generate_series(1, 110)
  group by intermediate_id -- Discard duplicates
)
limit 100
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want 100 random users who are less than 25 years old, my first suggestion is:

```
select u.*
from users u
where age < 25
order by random()
limit 100;
```

Or another method without sorting all the data would be:

```
select u.*
from users u cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from users where age < 25) x
where age < 25 and
      x < 2 * 100 / cnt
order by random()
limit 100;
```

This fetches roughly 200 rows and then does the sorting for the final 100.

Without a `WHERE` clause, my recommendation would be `TABLESAMPLE`.  If you have a very large table and know that a fair number of users are under 25, this might still be a possibility for reducing the number of rows before sampling.

Comment: Your suggestions are taking over 5 seconds to run which is way worse. The reason is that order by random() is sorting all of the found users and that takes N*Log(N). That was the reason for the post that I mentioned in the question. Your answer completely ignored all of that.

Comment: @yonikeren . . . The version in your question makes lots of assumptions about the ids which are not explained.  Without those assumptions, it is simply not going to work.  In addition, the subquery can generate duplicates, which I suppose is why you are generating 110 of them rather than 100 of them.

Comment: There are literally no assumptions (in my question), except having no column named "intermediate_id" in the original table. Can you point me to such assumptions, which would be more constructive than claiming that assumptions exist without pointing me to a single assumption?

Comment: There is no reference to a column "id" in my code, let alone assumptions on such column. The column intermediate_id is nothing but a product of "row_number()" which does produce numbers in a "dense way"...